# How convert a stored procedure result to a specific type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server and convert it to a function in my Entity Model, now how can I convert the output of my function to a given type in C# such `int,string` and so on?

Example:

```
Testentities test=new TestEntities();
object d=test.FunctionTest("Params");
```

Comment: Just a note to all who'd like to answer: the OP has **NOT** mentioned in his question here that the result is `List<object>` - so a **list of objects** (and not a single object, as the question would suggest....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a string:

```
Testentities test = new TestEntities();
object d = test.FunctionTest("Params");
string result = d.ToString();
```

To int:

```
Testentities test = new TestEntities();
object d = test.FunctionTest("Params");
int result = Convert.ToInt32(d);
```

The .NET [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class can convert to a lot of different types.

But a word of caution: **of course** you need to be certain that the target type is the right type, and even then - you need to be prepared for the fact the conversion might fail - put this in a `try...catch` block!

**Update:** after you've revealed that the result is in fact a `List<object>`, you need to do something like:

```
Testentities test = new TestEntities();
object d = test.FunctionTest("Params");

List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach(object o in d)
{
    results.Add(o.ToString());
}
```

and the same can be done with the `int` values (just use `Convert.ToInt32()` in the `foreach` loop

Comment: FunctionTest is a list<object>